# SPARQL equivalence for the SQL IN() operator

Tags: sparql

Is there a SPARQL equivalence for the SQL `IN()` operator? I filter my results and now use:

```
FILTER ( lang(?label) = 'en' )
```

I want something like:

```
FILTER ( lang(?label) IN ('en', 'de') )
```

Is this possible with SPARQL?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In SPARQL 1.1 [yes](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-in).

```
FILTER ( lang(?label) IN ('en', 'de') )
```

should work.

Pre-1.1 you'll need a big disjunction:

```
FILTER ( (lang(?label) = 'en') || (lang(?label) = 'de') )
```

Answer (score 3):

As per official [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-in) documentation,

**IN**

```
boolean  rdfTerm IN (expression, ...)
```

The IN operator tests whether the RDF term on the left-hand side is found in the values of list of expressions on the right-hand side. The test is done with "=" operator, which tests for the same value, as determined by the operator mapping.

A list of zero terms on the right-hand side is legal.

Errors in comparisons cause the IN expression to raise an error if the RDF term being tested is not found elsewhere in the list of terms.

The IN operator is equivalent to the SPARQL expression:

(lhs = expression1) || (lhs = expression2) || ...

**Examples:**

[image]

So, **IN** operator accepts **list of vales**. Hence below is an example, you can try with SPARQL using **FILTER +IN** syntax:

```
SELECT ?s1 
WHERE 
{
      ?s1 rdf:type dbpedia-owl:Scientist.
      FILTER (?s1 IN (<http://example.com/#1>,<http://example.com/#2>, <http://example.com/#3>)) 
 }
```